# corresponding intersection of two rows without zero in matlab

Tags: matlab, intersection

I have a matrix(m*n). for every two rows, how I can find number of corresponding elements that are not zero. for example for following rows:
r1=[1,3,0,4]   ,   r2=[5,0,0,4]
,the answer is 2. because first and fourth elements in two rows are not zero. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use matrix multiplication:

```
L = logical(m);     % convert the matrix to a logical matrix
result = L * L.';   % do matrix multiplication to compute number of corresponding elements
```

So the matrix element `result(i,j)` represents the number of corresponding elements between row `i` and row `j`.

Comment: @Hamid Glad if it can help! Consider marking the answer as accepted if it is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to consider each block ot two rows; that is, first row with second, third with fourth etc.

Reshape the `m`×`n` input matrix `A` into an `2`×`m/2`×`n` 3D array and then use `all` and `sum` along the appropriate dimensions:

```
result = sum(all(reshape(A, 2, [], size(A,2)), 1), 3);
```

As an example, for

```
A =
     0     2     0     0     0
     2     0     0     2     1
     1     0     1     2     2
     1     1     2     1     0
     1     1     1     1     2
     1     2     1     1     1
```

the result is

```
>> result = sum(all(reshape(A, 2, [], size(A,2)), 1), 3)
result =
     0     3     5
```